# ctypes error AttributeError symbol not found, OS X 10.7.5

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a simple test function on C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

char fun() {
    printf( "%i", 12 );

   return 'y';
}
```

compiling:

```
gcc -o test.so -shared -fPIC test.cpp
```

and using it in python with ctypes:

```
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import c_char_p

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('test.so')
hello = lib.fun
hello.restype = c_char_p

print('res', hello())
```

but then I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./sort_c.py", line 10, in <module>
    hello = lib.fun   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self)) 
AttributeError: dlsym(0x100979b40, fun): symbol not found
```

Where is a problem?

using:

> Mac Os X 10.7.5 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first problem is C++ *name mangling*.  If you run `nm` on your `.so` file you will get something like this:

```
nm test.so
0000000000000f40 T __Z3funv
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

If you mark it as C style when compiled with C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" char fun()
#else
char fun(void)
#endif
{
    printf( "%i", 12 );

   return 'y';
}
```

`nm` gives:

```
0000000000000f40 T _fun
                 U _printf
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Your second problem is that the python will die with a `Segmentation fault: 11` (on OS X).  The C++ is returning a `char`, whereas you are marking it in python as a pointer to a char.  Use:

```
hello.restype = c_char
```

instead (alter your `import` statement to match).

EDIT:  as @eryksun pointed out, you should not use `gcc`, you should use `g++` instead.  Otherwise the correct C++ runtime will not be linked.  To check on `OS X`:

```
otool -L test.so
```

(`ldd`, the tool normally used on UNIX/Linux, is not distributed with OS X)

Comment: Does using `gcc` link a C++ program to the proper C++ runtime in OS X? I'd expect it to require `g++`. I know it doesn't matter in this case since the sample code is just using C standard library functions.

Comment: @eryksun:  `gcc` does compile it as C++ if the source file has the suffix `.cpp`, but you are right, `g++` is preferred.  I didn't mention it in my answer because there was a comment on it (yours?).  It is demonstrably C++ because the name mangling is different with the conditional `extern "C"` (see body of post).

Comment: `gcc` compiles the source as C++, but on Linux it doesn't link with libstdc++.so.6, so loading the library fails if it requires the C++ lib.

Comment: @eryksun:  I almost replied saying that it linked correctly on OS X, and then I realised I had been using `g++` for my testing all along!  I guess I used the right one without thinking and I didn't copy the OP's compilation line.  I added a comment.  Thanks!