# python not importing module-- perhaps gcc being used to compile the python library instead of clang?

Tags: python, c++, macos, gcc, clang

Mac OSX here, Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)|.  I'm trying to install a python module called, say, foo.  I run

```
python setup.py install
```

I get

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /Users/jir955/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kenlm-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Users/jir955/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kenlm-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

However, after

```
import foo
```

I get the error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", 
line 1, in <module> ImportError: foo.so, 2):
 Symbol not found: __ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E
Referenced from: foo.so Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Errors in the past have occurred when I tried to compile something with gcc instead of clang.  (At some point I downloaded gcc on my own, for some reason, but then I brew uninstalled gcc.)  I have avoided the errors by sometimes adding -toolset=clang.

I have tried adding

```
 os.environ["CC"] = "/usr/bin/clang"
 os.environ["CXX"] = "/usr/bin/clang"
```

to setup.py, and also modifying bashrc to include

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

But these things have not worked.  One person I talked to suggested that the problem was that I compiled python libraries using gcc instead of clang, but if this is the case I don't know how how to fix that either.

Edit: with

```
nm foo.so
```

an excerpt of what I get is

```
0000000000072a60 S __ZTIN4util9ExceptionE
U __ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E
U __ZTISt11range_error
```

Comment: Python uses C, not C++.  That looks like C++ name mangling.  Is it C++?  I played with this a couple of days ago, not exactly the same, but look at :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983220/ctypes-error-attributeerror-symbol-not-found-os-x-10-7-5/30983638#30983638

Comment: Is this one of your modules?

Comment: @cdarke Ok, this is an excerpt of what I get with nm.  It seems to be undefined.  Do I still do what you suggest?

`0000000000072a60 S __ZTIN4util9ExceptionE U __ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E U __ZTISt11range_error`

Comment: @cdarke So if I am reading this correctly, it is looking for the symbol in the CXX11 library right?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `ios_base` is the C++ stream library (cout etc.), nothing to do with the iPhone operating system!   The point is, why is that module compiled n C++ and not C?